# internal server error 500 retrofit in android?

Tags: android, web-services, api, retrofit

I am implementation for Retrofit on api call using images-upload base64Encode string. it is sending data perfect but Retrofit return response **Internal Server Error 500** and i am sending request type is Body custom class. Plz help me what i do.

```
@Headers("Accept:application/json")
@POST(RestClient.postRegister)
Call<RegisterResp> getRegisterResponse(@Body RequestRegisterVo requestRegisterVo);

  Call<RegisterResp> call = MyApplication.getRestClient().getApplicationServices().getRegisterResponse(requestRegisterVo);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<RegisterResp>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<RegisterResp> call, Response<RegisterResp> response) {
                    if (Other.isValidResp(response)) {
                    // success Log.i(TAG,"Register successfully");
                    } else {
                        hideDialog();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<RegisterResp> call, Throwable t) {
                    hideDialog();
                    showToast(t.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Is it working in REST api clients? like `postman` ?

Comment: Yes. It is working

Comment: try this for the header  @Headers({
            "Accept:application/json"
    })

Comment: Ok,Lets i will try. Thank You !!!

Comment: Sorry. Not working @Headers({ "Accept:application/json" }). So, any other solution

Comment: I could help if your provide me with the base url and end point and request or any example of the api or you could use retrofit log to see what's happening internally

Comment: What converter are you using? Gson?

Comment: @Wizard GsonFormat on class body

Answer (score 0):

The same issue I had to face it, I got a solution in my case-

there is parameter issue, I was sending parameters in String and at the backend, they required Integer parameters.

You also checkout may be there is the issue with parameters or second reason is the URL issue so check it URL also.